# Numpy vectorization algorithms to sum up numbers with the same time stamps

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have two arrays P and T. P[i] is a number, whose time stamp is T[i]; There might be duplicated time stamps.

I want to produce another two arrays Q and U, where Q[i] has time stamp U[i], and Q[i] is the sum of all elements in P that have time stamp U[i];

For example, for

P = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
T = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

I will produce

Q = [3, 12]
U = [0, 1];

Is there a fast way of doing this in numpy, that hopefully vectorizes it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using numpy 1.4 or better:

```
import numpy as np

P = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) 
T = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1])

U,inverse = np.unique(T,return_inverse=True)
Q = np.bincount(inverse,weights=P)
print (Q, U)
# (array([  3.,  12.]), array([0, 1]))
```

---

Please note that this is **not** the fastest solution. I tested the speed this way:

```
import numpy as np

N = 1000
P = np.repeat(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),N)
T = np.repeat(np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1]),N)

def using_bincount():
    U,inverse = np.unique(T,return_inverse=True)
    Q = np.bincount(inverse,weights=P)
    return Q,U
    # (array([  3.,  12.]), array([0, 1]))

def using_lc():
    U = list(set(T))
    Q = [sum([p for (p,t) in zip(P,T) if t == u]) for u in U]
    return Q,U

def using_slice():
    U = np.unique(T)
    Q = np.array([P[T == u].sum() for u in U])
    return Q,U
```

For small arrays, [wim's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003046/numpy-vectorization-algorithms-to-sum-up-numbers-with-the-same-time-stamps/8003121#8003121) is faster (N=1):

```
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.using_lc()'
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.4 usec per loop
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.using_slice()'
10000 loops, best of 3: 66.8 usec per loop
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.using_bincount()'
10000 loops, best of 3: 52.8 usec per loop
```

For large arrays, [joris's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003046/numpy-vectorization-algorithms-to-sum-up-numbers-with-the-same-time-stamps/8003192#8003192) is faster (N=1000):

```
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.using_lc()'
100 loops, best of 3: 9.93 msec per loop
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.using_slice()'
1000 loops, best of 3: 390 usec per loop
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.using_bincount()'
1000 loops, best of 3: 846 usec per loop
```

I doubt it matters in this case, but benchmarks can change depending on version of numpy, python, OS, or hardware. It would not hurt to repeat these benchmarks on your machine.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
P = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) 
T = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1])

U = np.unique(T)
Q = np.array([P[T == u].sum() for u in U])
```

gives

```
In [17]: print Q, U
[3 12] [0 1]
```

Not really vectorized, but faster than the solution with lists.

If you want more powerful of this kind of group-by functions, maybe you can take a look at [pandas](http://pandas.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: very nice!  though i would use `Q = np.array([P[T==u].sum() for u in U])` for consistency.

Comment: How do you measure it as faster than the solution with lists?  Because I get `10000 loops, best of 3: 36.7 us per loop` for this one, 10x slower than the list comprehension `100000 loops, best of 3: 3 us per loop`.

Comment: I should have explained it more when I stated that. I did also some timeit tests, but on a larger array, and you can see in the timings of unutbu that in that case it is faster. So it depends on the array you want to process.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> P = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; T = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
>>> U = list(set(T))
>>> Q = [sum([p for (p,t) in zip(P,T) if t == u]) for u in U]
>>> print Q, U
[3, 12] [0, 1]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think he's looking for a standard lib solution as he indicates multiple times that he's looking for vectorized solution using numpy data structures.

Comment: The examples in the questions have lists... but for numpy array's it's even easier with using `np.where`